# Distance between grounding rods

Tags: grounding

Here in Hampshire County, WV we are required to have 2 grounding rods.  Question #1 How deep do they need to be?  #2 This mountain was formed by a rock glacier before I was born.  I can drill down 18", but certainly not 6-8'.  Any ideas?

Comment: This is an AHJ question.  The AHJ is the Authority Having Jurisdiction, or town electrical inspector. She has worked out what works there.   Are you planning to pour a concrete foundation?   Last week I was watching the PureLivingForLife YouTube channel as they did their foundation pour, and it never occurred to them to provide an Ufer ground. Well, their plans are to be off grid anyway...

Comment: Yes, are you planning to to pour a concrete foundation, or a founded/footed slab for something else? If so, will there be sub-slab insulation or vapor barrier sheeting, and if either is present, how will it be detailed at the footing to slab transition?